# Django admin - How to calculate a field value depending on other model field values

Tags: django, django-admin

I have this scenario:
A Service repair that might include repair/installation of multiple spare Parts in a machine. For every spare part involved in the service repair, the technician can select its state (new, used, refurbished). In a separate table called PartCostRate, I map a cost percentage for a state:

models.py

```
class Part(models.Model):
    item_code = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField('Part Name', max_length=128)
    exw_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=6)

class PartCostRate(models.Model):
    PART_STATES = (
        ('N', 'New'),
        ('U', 'Used'),
        ('R', 'Refurbished'),
    )
    state = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=Part_STATES)
    rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)

class Service(models.Model):
    service_code = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    parts = models.ManyToManyField(Part, through='ServicePart')

class ServicePart(models.Model):
    PART_STATES = (
        ('N', 'New'),
        ('U', 'Used'),
        ('R', 'Refurbished'),
    )
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service)
    part = models.ForeignKey(Part)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=PART_STATE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=6)
```

admin.py

```
class ServicePartInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ServicePart
    extra = 1
    verbose_name = 'Repaired / Installed Part'

class ServiceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   inlines = [ServicePartInline,]
```

From the admin interface, how can I calculate the cost of the part (from the inline of serviceadmin) depending on the selected state and quantity. For a select of Used, I need to query the PartCostRate model to check what is the rate of Used and then check the exw_price of that part and then do the calculation without forgetting the quantity.

I am not sure how to do that from the admin. Does it require javascript in order to interactivley show the calculated cost in its field. Because sometimes they might change it manually.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do it

1) Javascript like you say. Look at this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/media/). You'll see how to hook your own script files into django admin

2) Create your own modelform, extend your ServiceAdmin setting form value ([check this out](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form)) form and update the values in form at form save.

Comment: Am I right if I say: I cannot update the cost field value depending on the selected state before the hit of the save button in the 2nd option? I want the user to see the value, because sometimes (for certain reasons) they need to change it before saving. If true, then I am left with option 1.

Comment: You are correct. Everything that takes place in form save() method is done after user has hit "save" button. But that does not have to be a problem, as you can present the same view after saving the form. Although that sort of changes the rest of django admin flow and might not be a good option :P.