# how to calculate field in django admin model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

i have a model that i have added to my django admin panel

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin

class Employee(models.Model):
   fee = models.IntegerField(null=False)
   vat = models.IntegerField(null=False)
```

and have added this my admin panel

```
admin.site.register(Employee, EmployeeAdmin)
 readonly_fields('vat',)
```

so while adding a new employee, the  admin inputs the fee amount, id like vat to be calculated and shown as a direct result of entering the vat. how can create this calculation on the fly as the admin is entering the fee

Comment: Your question is quite unintellegible. That said, in order to perform calculations "on the fly" you will need more js than django code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20220394/django-admin-how-to-calculate-a-field-value-depending-on-other-model-field-val might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i might be completely wrong here, but couldn't you just use a property for that instead of storing `vat` in the database?

on your model, declare:

```
@property
def vat(self):
    return calculation_of_vat(self.fee)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can override the save method:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.vat=self.calculate_vat(self.fee)
    super(ClassModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```